# tapply function with multiple groups

Tags: r

trying to reshape some data tables using tapply.  Straight forward enough if you have one factor, one variable, and your desired mathematical function.  However I have some datasets where I'd like to reformat with two (or perhaps more) grouping levels.

Consider

```
x<-1:20 # variable
y<-factor(rep(letters[1:5], each=4)) # first grouping variable
z<-factor(rep(letters[6:7], each=10)) # second grouping variable
tapply(x,z,sum) # summarized table for factor z

  f   g 
 55 155

tapply(x,y,sum) # summarized table for factor y

 a  b  c  d  e
10 26 42 58 74
```

However, my desired output is would be a table that is something like:

```
f  f  f  f  f g  g  g  g  g
a  b  c  d  e a  b  c  d  e
6  8  10....etc
```

So, just trying to keep higher level grouping in tables.  Sorry if a simple question, I've looked around and can't find anything.

Comment: Something like `ftable(z, x)` ?

Comment: Where do `6`, `8`, `10`, etc. come from? The sum of `x` where `y==a & z==f` is 10, not 6. (If you're after the sum of `x` for each combination of `y` and `z`, you can use `aggregate(x, list(y, z), sum)`)

Comment: @jbaums, why not stick with `tapply` since it's the workhorse for `aggregate` anyway? `tapply(x, list(y, z), sum)` for example, or `as.data.frame(as.table(tapply(x, list(y, z), sum)))` perhaps.

Comment: @AnandaMahto sure - that's perfectly fine. Our approaches give different output, so I guess it just depends on exactly how the OP wants the results presented (which isn't clear to me). Though I'd argue that the `aggregate` is simpler to code/read (while perhaps slower to evaluate) than your second example.

Answer (score 3):

This is my code Ive used on my own data

```
with(reduced, do.call(rbind, tapply(WR, list(period, no.C), 
                           function(x) c(WR = mean(x), SD = sd(x)))))

reduced = my data frame
WR is the variable I want to calculate the mean from
period is one of my grouping variables.  in this case its binary 
no.C is another grouping variable - here I have 3 groups
```

The rest of the equation is the function, but that can easily be replaced by just writing mean (or sum or whatever other statistic you are after) if you only want one value, but I also want it to calculate the standard deviation and I am binding it into a little table that I can print later with the `rbind`.  Sorry I didn't put the answer into context of your data - but I was confused as to what exactly you wanted.

Basically, in using the `list` you can start to create as many grouping values as you want while still using `tapply`.

You can also do something similar with `aggregate` - see this quick [web page](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-apply-to-create-tabular-summaries-in-r.html) for a tidy answer and examples to your question.

```
with(reduced, aggregate(WR, list(period, no.C), mean))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dplyr package, much easier and much faster if you are dealing with large datasets. However, it only works with data frames.

```
d <- data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=z)
```

For the first case:

```
groups <- group_by(d,z)
summarise(groups,sum(x))

  z sum(x)
1 f     55
2 g    155
```

For the second case:

```
groups <- group_by(d,y)
summarise(groups,sum(x))

  y sum(x)
1 a     10
2 b     26
3 c     42
4 d     58
5 e     74
```

And for the last case:

```
groups <- group_by(d,z,y)
summarise(groups,sum(x))

  z y sum(x)
1 f a     10
2 f b     26
3 f c     19
4 g c     23
5 g d     58
6 g e     74
```

Comment: One last inquiry, say that my z and y factors in a dataset, x is my measured parameter, and now I have a list of species that I'd like to have as columns.  In each column (or species) I would have the sum of the measured parameter.  So, trying to add columns within which the total sum would be distributed.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what exactly you mean. Can you provide an example?